# Zoom HTML5 canvas context to bounding box

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have arbitrary data points with x/y coordinates that I want to draw on an HTML5 canvas. I would like to zoom the canvas context to fit the data points. How can I adjust the canvas scale and translation to fit a specific bounding box?

My searches for this topic show various hits using different libraries like d3.js, or geospatial databases, but I'd like a pure JavaScript/HTML5 solution. I can (have) hand-written combinations of `ctx.scale()` and `ctx.translate()` that via hand-tweaking can match a particular set of points, but I want a general solution that I can feed a bounding box (e.g. x,y,w,h) to and have the context transformed.

Comment: I didn't cast that vote, but this question deserves a downvote indeed. It doesn't show any research effort, it talks of data points and then of bounding boxes, without any precision on what these are etc. All in all, that's indeed a low quality question that if asked by a new user, without the self-answer would probably already have been closed. Even if self-answered, questions must meet SO's standards.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for your perspective. I'll edit the question to include the fact that I did my research first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that takes an HTML canvas context and a bounding box—specified as `minX`, `minY`, either `maxX`/`maxY` or `width`/`height`, and an optional `padding` value—and calculates the scale and translation needed to make the canvas drawing area focus only on that box.

I've assumed that a symmetric scale is desired, with extra content shown on the sides or top/bottom, based on aspect ratio.

```js
function zoomContext(ctx, bbox={minX:0, minY:0, maxX:10, maxY:20, padding:0}) {
    let {minX:x, minY:y, maxX, maxY, width:w, height:h, padding} = bbox
    w ||= maxX - x
    h ||= maxY - y
    if (padding) {
        x -= padding
        y -= padding
        w += padding*2
        h += padding*2
    }
    const cx = x + w / 2
          cy = y + h / 2,
          sx = ctx.canvas.width / w,
          sy = ctx.canvas.height / h
    const symmetricScale = Math.min(sx, sy)

    ctx.resetTransform()
    ctx.scale(symmetricScale, symmetricScale)
    ctx.translate(-cx, -cy)
}
```

Before calling this you may want to ensure that the internal height and width of the canvas match its display size (in case you are scaling the canvas using CSS):

```js
myCanvas.width = myCanvas.offsetWidth
myCanvas.height = myCanvas.offsetHeight
```

Comment: Instead of `ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)` you may prefer `ctx.resetTransform()`, or even you could include the next scale `ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, 0, 0)`, and why not the translate too `ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, -cx * scale, -cy * scale)`

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks, those are good suggestions! I didn't know about `resetTransform()`, so that's far cleaner. The direct-setting of the matrix is possibly more performant, but I'll omit that to keep the code more DRY and also more self-explanatory for those who don't know what it's doing.